# Updating workout in HKHealthStore

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit

So, I am able to save a HKWorkout and HKQuantitySample to HealthKit, but need to have the ability to update those records.  From what I can see, I can't update a HKQuantitySample details if I do a HKSampleQuery

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Samples in HealthKit are immutable.  To modify a sample that was previously saved your app should save a new sample with updated values and delete the old one.